# How to avoid or close persistent (keep-alive) connection in blazor client hosted app?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am playing with blazor client hosted tech. I don't know what I did to the app that after successful login then logout, the requests without authorization header still get correct response even in new tab of internet browser. I have to close the browser completely and open it again to see log-out behavior. The controller decorated with [Authorize]. I see in the request header, there is "connection: keep-alive".  in the client side app the only http behavior is changed through below code

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", savedToken);
```

Is there function to force http requests not be persistent?